# How to calculate percentage using % as a postfix unary operator in Swift 3 and still be able to use % for modulo?

Tags: ios, swift

I declared the `%` token as a post-fix operator in order to calculate percentage but Xcode reports

```
`% is not a postfix unary operator`
```

My test code *below* is based on an example found [here](http://www.codingexplorer.com/custom-operators-swift/). I've also checked Apple’s latest documentation for the [syntax for Operator Declaration](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID380) but it gave no clue why Xcode complains.

How do I calculate percentage using `%` ? And assuming I get it to work, how would I then revert to using `%` for a modulo operation in another function elsewhere in the same class ?

Can someone offer a working example based on my code in Playground ?

**1.     %** meaning **percentage**

```
postfix operator %

var percentage = 25%

postfix func % (percentage: Int) -> Double {
    return (Double(percentage) / 100)
}
```

**2.     %** meaning **remainder**

```
let number = 11
let divisor = 7

print(number % divisor)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just move

```
var percentage = 25%
```

under

```
postfix func % (percentage: Int) -> Double {
    return (Double(percentage) / 100)
}
```

Like so

```
postfix operator %

postfix func % (percentage: Int) -> Double {
    return (Double(percentage) / 100)
}

var percentage = 25%
```

**Reason**: your code would work in an app, but not in a playground, because a playground *interprets* the code from top to bottom. It doesn't see the `postfix func` declaration located below `var percentage`, so at the point of `var percentage` it gives you an error, because it doesn't yet know what to do with it.

Comment: FreeNickname, moving the statement has cleared the message in Xcode. Thanks.

Comment: Your explanation also makes sense. I rarely use playground which is probably why I missed this.

Comment: Alas, the code doesn't work in an app, so I submitted a new question. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932230/in-swift-3-what-does-this-mean-member-operator-must-have-at-least-one-argu

Comment: @Greg, I made sure it works in the app prior to leaving my answer. I'm glad this new question is already resolved, and I'm glad I could help :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me :

```
postfix operator %

postfix func % ( percentage: Int) -> Double {
    return Double(percentage) / 100
}


print(25%) // prints 0.25
print(7%5) // prints 2
```

Comment: but can you `print(7%5)` ?

Comment: @Fonix Yes, it gives "2"

Answer (score 0):

```
postfix operator %

postfix func % (percentage: Int) -> Double {
  return (Double(percentage) / 100)
}

var percentage = 25%

8%3
```

working in playground Xcode 8.1