# Member operator '%' must have at least one argument of type 'ViewController’

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I am trying to create a simple Swift 3 template with a custom function for calculating percentage using postfix unary operator in an Xcode app. This may seem like a duplicate question because the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40927843/2348597) in my previous post already shows how to do this in Playground. But I have since found that the custom function doesn't work the same way in an Xcode project.

In the template *below*, I declared the `’operator' at file scope` (or at least I believe I did). But when the postfix function is declared, Xcode advises that

```
    Operator '%' declared in type 'ViewController' must be 'static'
```

and offers a fix-it to insert `static`. With `static` inserted Xcode then advises

```
    Member operator '%' must have at least one argument of type 'ViewController’.
```

Can anyone explain why the `%` function needs to be `static` in the Xcode project and what the last error message means in the context of the same line (*see below*) ? Thanks

**Draft Template**

```
import UIKit

postfix operator %

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var percentage = Double()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    percentage = 25%
    print(percentage)
    }

static postfix func % (percentage: Int) -> Double {
    return (Double(percentage) / 100)
    }
}
```

**EDITED Template**

Here's the working template based on the accepted answer. I hadn't understood what is meant by declaring the operator at file scope.

```
import UIKit


postfix operator %

postfix func % (percentage: Int) -> Double {
return (Double(percentage) / 100)
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

var percentage = Double()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    percentage = 25%
    print(percentage)
    }
}
```

**FOOTNOTE**

Building on the accepted answer, custom operator functions grouped in a single file may now be accessed from other files in the same project. To see more visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40941827/how-to-access-a-custom-function-from-any-file-in-the-same-swift-project).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I declared the ’operator' at file scope

No, you didn't. You defined it in the scope of the
`UIViewController` definition:

```
postfix operator %

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // ...

    static postfix func % (percentage: Int) -> Double {
        return (Double(percentage) / 100)
    }
}
```

One *can* define operators as static member functions of a type in Swift 3,
but only if they take at least one argument of that type.

Move the declaration to the file scope to fix the problem:

```
postfix operator %

postfix func % (percentage: Int) -> Double {
    return (Double(percentage) / 100)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // ...

}
```

Comment: I also tried moving the function to the file scope as you suggested where it is no longer static. This time I tested it and it works confirming your answer. Thanks.

Comment: you may be interested in the solution using static postfix functions. Regardless, I’ve learnt a lot from your input. Thanks. See Final Edit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40941827/how-to-access-a-custom-function-from-any-file-in-the-same-swift-project

Answer (score 1):

other alternative if you want to use closures in **Swift 3**:

```
import UIKit

typealias Filter = (CIImage) -> CIImage

infix operator >>>
func >>> (filter1: @escaping Filter, filter2: @escaping Filter) -> Filter{
    return { image in
        filter2( filter1( image))
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //...
}
```

Eidhof, Chris; Kugler, Florian; Swierstra, Wouter. Functional Swift: Updated for Swift 3 (Kindle Location 542). GbR Florian Kugler & Chris Eidhof. Kindle Edition.