# How to access a custom function from any file in the same Swift project?

Tags: swift, swift3

If the postfix operator of a custom function is declared at file scope - as in my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932230/member-operator-must-have-at-least-one-argument-of-type-viewcontroller) - there must be a way to access such a function from another Swift 3 file in the same Xcode project.

Apple’s documentation on custom functions states that [“*New operators are declared at a global level …*“](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID46) so I can presume the creators of Swift 3 would consider it important for a custom function to be accessed globally. But for a novice in Swift it is not self-evident how I would do this.

Based on code in my previous accepted answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40932403/2348597)) what would I need to do so a custom function can be accessed from another file elsewhere in the project ?

---

**FINAL EDIT**

The solution is embarrassingly simple (see [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40941948/2348597)) and hopefully other Swift novices may also find it useful.

A `postfix operator %` is declared globally while an `Extension` of `Int` reads an `Int` variable from another file. Extensions of `Double` and `CGFloat` as well as `Int` are also possible.

**CustomOperators.swift**

```
import UIKit

postfix operator %

extension Double {
    static postfix func % (n: Double) -> Double {
     return Double(n) /  100
    }
}

extension Int {
    static postfix func % (n: Int) -> Double {
        return Double(n) /  100
    }
}

extension CGFloat {
    static postfix func % (n: CGFloat) -> Double {
        return Double(n) /  100
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let test1: Double   = 93.7
    let test2: Int      = 80
    let test3: CGFloat  = 70

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    print(test1%)       // prints '0.937'
    print(test2%)       // prints '0.8'
    print(test3%)       // prints '0.7'

    }
}
```

*Thanks marosoiae, and also Martin R and unniversal for your input.*

---

**EDIT 2**

Martin R’s comments prompted me to try a further example with my custom postfix function defined in `Utils` but in file scope rather than as a static postfix function. `Utils` becomes an empty class for custom functions all defined in file scope outside the class.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let value: Int  = 25

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    example1()
    example2()
}


func example1() {

    // 1. call to a function in Utils with an explicit value 
    // and nothing returned from Utils. 
    // Note this uses literal postfix syntax i.e. 25%

    Utils.25%


    // Debug message:
    // Type 'Utils' has no member '25'

    }


func example2() {

    // 2. call to a function in Utils with an argument 
    // declared in UIViewController and nothing returned from Utils

    Utils.(Int: value)%

    // Debug message
    // Expected member name following '.'

    }
}
```

`Utils.swift` now compiles but from debug messages that Xcode reports with both examples, it is clear that the token '`%`' is expected immediately following the '`.`'.

Even without returning a variable from `Utils.swift`, this is obviously not how to call a postfix function in `Utils.swift` from a file elsewhere in the project. My question remains: how would I do it ?

---

**EDIT 1**

At this point it might help to include some code so I created a class with static functions, following the syntax (as far as possible) used in Unniversal's answer. I decided to try static functions if these help avoid cluttering the global scope with methods that should be owned by a class/struct.

**File 1 - Utils**

```
import UIKit

postfix operator %

class Utils {

    static func yourFunction(){
    //Do your stuff here
    }

    static func yourFunction1(value: Int) {
    print(value)
    }

    static postfix func % (percentage: Int) -> Double {
        return (Double(percentage) / 100)
    }    
}
```

The static function `%` reports

```
    Member operator '%' must have at least one argument of type 'Utils'
```

which I’d expect to disappear once an argument is supplied from another file.

The following code shows four ways I tried to supply an argument to static functions in Utils. I ran the project with one example at a time

**File 2 - UIViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let value: Int  = 25
    var percentage  = Double()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//        example1()
//        example2()
//        example3()
//        example4()
    }





func example1() {

    // 1. call to a function in Utils with no argument and no return (i.e. suggested answer)

    Utils.yourfunction()

    // Debug messages:
    // Type 'Utils' has no member 'yourfunction'
    // Did you mean 'yourFunction'?
    // Did you mean 'yourFunction1'?

    }


func example2() {

    // 2. call to a function in Utils with argument and no return

    Utils.yourfunction1(Int: Int)

    // Debug messages:
    // Type 'Utils' has no member 'yourfunction'
    // Did you mean 'yourFunction'?
    // Did you mean 'yourFunction1'?

    }

func example3() {

    // 3. call to a function in Utils with argument and returning a value for percentage

    Utils.%() {
        return Int(percentage)
    }

    // Debug message:
    // Use of unresolved operator '.%'

    }

func example4()  {

    // 4. call to a function in Utils with argument and returning a value for percentage

    percentage = Utils.%(Int: value) -> Int {
        return Int(percentage)
    }

    // Debug messages:
    // Use of unresolved operator '.%'
    // Expected type before '->'
    // Expected type after '->'

    }
}
```

As far as I can see, static functions `Utils.yourFunction` and `Utils.yourFunction1` can’t be accessed from outside Utils, as shown in example 1 and 2. And the postfix operator `%` seems to cause Xcode to report `Use of unresolved operator ‘.%’`, as shown in example 3 and 4. However these problems might be the way I adapted the syntax used by Unniversal.

Comment: This is still the same problem as in your previous question. You have to move `static postfix func %` out of the `Utils` definition. Utils.swift does *not compile* because of that error, and that causes all the other compiler errors. The problem cannot "disappear" by "supplying an argument from another file".

Comment: Martin R, thanks. I've created two more examples based on your observation. See EDIT 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any function declared at file scope will have the implicit scope `internal` and will be visible in the rest of the project/module.

I recommend reading the [access control guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID3) for more information.

Edit:

I'm still not sure what you're trying to do, but it looks like you are mixing global functions with static methods and custom operators.

If what you want is to declare a custom operator that you can use in any other file in the project, the solution is in the [documentation that you linked](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID46) in your question.

So this is what you need to declare a custom % (as you defined it) for the Int type:

**CustomOperators.swift**

```
postfix operator %

extension Int {

    static postfix func % (n: Int) -> Double {
        return Double(n) / 100
    }

}
```

**main.swift**

```
print(90%) //outputs "0.9"
```

That's all there is to it. You simply declare the operator globally: `postfix operator %` and you define the operator function as a static method in a extension on the Int type.

Now you can use your new operator in other files (like I did in `main.swift`).

Comment: you nailed it! This has to be the accepted answer. See my final edit. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you want a function to be accessed globally I would recommend to create a class that has static functions. For example

```
class Utils {
   static func yourFunction(){
      //Do your stuff here
   }
}
```

To use it :

```
Utils.yourfunction()
```

Comment: This. More than the other answer although it would also work. Avoid cluttering the global scope with methods that should be owned by a class/struct.

Comment: Unniverzal, I tried to workout how a postfix operator can be used with your template. See my edit.

Comment: unniverzal, you may be interested in the solution. See my final edit. Regardless, I’ve learnt a lot from your input. Thanks