# How to make a custom function with + operator in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, macos, operator-overloading

I'm looking at this code from [rosettacode.org](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_two_or_more_lists#Swift) and one of the functions defined within it is this:

```
class MyClass {
    static func + <T>(el: T, arr: [T]) -> [T] {
        var ret = arr
    
        ret.insert(el, at: 0)
    
        return ret
    }
}
```

The compiler has this to  say about it:

> Member operator '+' must have at least one argument of type 'MyClass'

I updated the method to make it it static, as follows:

```
static func + <T: Sequence>(el: T, arr: [T]) -> [T] {
    var ret = arr
    
    ret.insert(el, at: 0)
    
    return ret
}
```

That doesn't get rid of the compiler error. I tried Googling it, but I'm not coming up with any short, simple answers. Any ideas how I might quell this error?

Comment: Please share more code on what type you want to add this on. What custom class you want to add this functionality to?

Comment: There's a link at the top. I'm basically copying the code from the link in the post and the compiler is whining about the + side. I think it it needs to be for a `Sequence`

Comment: The first function compiles without problems (as a free function, not inside  a struct or class).

Comment: I've got it in a class called `TableGenerator { // function above }`

Comment: Static member functions of a type require at least one argument of that type, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/40932403/1187415. – The question is: *Why* do you define it inside a class definition?

Comment: ⚠️ Warning: the performance of this operator will be total dogshit. Not only is it doing repeated prepends to an array (each one of which requires an `O(arr.count)` shift of all element), but it's first making a mutable CoW copy, which costs a full `O(arr.count)` copy. Depending on your use-case, it might be better to: 1) append to the array a bunch, and reverse once at the end, 2) make this mutate a single array in-place, or 3) use `Deque<T>` from the Swift collections package for fast prepend operations.

Comment: Btw, what is the advantage of defining such an operator `+` over calling `array.insert(_:at:)` or `array.append(_:)`?

Comment: @MartinR `insert(_:at:)` doesn't return the array, so you can't chain it like you can with `a + b + c + theTail`. It kind of acts like a "cons" operator

Comment: @Alexander: But `+` is left-associative, so `1 + 2 + 3 + []` returns `[6]`, and `1 + (2 + (3 + []))` returns `[1, 2, 3]`. Not very intuitive IMO.

Comment: Ah interesting! Yeah, I super wouldn't recommend this, but a performant version of `[1] + tail` would be nice to have (for example to work with Deque).

Comment: Thank you both for your input. I'm doing truth table generation. I'll incorporate your suggestions into future optimizations of this. For now, I'm just writing a MacOS app to automate writing unit tests. I'll post a link here when I'm done.

Comment: @Adrian not related to your question but I would constrain `T` to `RangeReplaceableCollection` and simply return a `CollectionOfOne(element) + collection`. This would support strings as well.

Comment: `func + <T: RangeReplaceableCollection>(element: T.Element, collection: T) -> T {` `CollectionOfOne(element) + collection` `}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by @MartinR in the comments, you need to put this function at the top level (NOT inside a class).

```
import Foundation

// Will compile fine from here as is
func + <T>(el: T, arr: [T]) -> [T] {
    var ret = arr
    ret.insert(el, at: 0)
    return ret
}

class TableGenerator {
    // will require at least one argument of the function to be of `TableGenerator` type
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Tarun! That did the trick :) It needed to be declared globally.